# ActiveRecord 4.2 includes and ordering by count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm writing a search for a project I'm working on. It is meant to be able to search the body of articles and produce a list of their authors, ordered by the number of matching articles and including the relevant articles only, not all of their articles.

I currently have the following query:

```
Author.includes(:articles).where('articles.body ilike ?', '%foo%').references(:articles)
```

The use of includes in this case makes it so that all the relevant articles (not all articles) are preloaded, that's exactly what I want. However, when it comes to ordering by the number of included articles, I'm not sure how to proceed.

I should note I want to do this in ActiveRecord because pagination will be applied after the query. Not after a Ruby solution.

I should note I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

**Edit: using raw SQL**

This seems to work on its own like so:

`Author.includes(:articles).where('articles.body ilike ?', '%foo%').references(:articles).select('authors.*, (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM articles WHERE articles.author_id = authors.id) AS article_count').order('article_count DESC')`

This works fine. However, if I add `.limit(1)` it breaks.

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "article_count" does not exist`

Any idea why adding limit breaks it? The query seems very different too

`SELECT  DISTINCT "authors"."id", article_count AS alias_0 FROM "authors" LEFT OUTER JOIN "articles" ON "articles"."author_id" = "authors"."id" WHERE (articles.body ilike '%microsoft%')  ORDER BY article_count DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an out of the box solution for this.  You have to write raw sql to do this but you can combine it with existing `ActiveRecord` queries.

```
Author
  .includes(:articles)
  .select('authors.*, (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM articles WHERE articles.author_id = authors.id) AS article_count')
  .order('article_count DESC')
```

So the only thing to explain here is the `select` part.  The first part, `authors.*`, selects all fields under the authors table and this is the default.  Since we want to also count the number of articles, we create a subquery and pass its result as one of the pseudo columns of authors (we called it `article_count`).  The last part is to just call `order` using `article_count`.

This solution assumes a couple of things which you'll have to fine tune depending on your setup.

- `Author` by convention in rails maps to an authors table.  If it is an STI (inherits from a `User` class and is using users table), you'll need to change `authors` to `users`.
- `articles.author_id` assumes that the foreign key is `author_id` (and essentially, an article is only written by a single author).  Change to whatever the foreign key is.

So given that, you'll have an array of authors ordered by the number of articles they've written.

Comment: I updated the question with more information. Your suggestion works fine on its own but when I try to add a limit clause it falls apart saying there's no column called `article_count`.

Comment: I actually also didn't know what's going on when you add `limit` but I made some checking and it turns out that adding `limit` will result in 2 sql calls.  first one is the query raising the error and rails does this to get ids of the authors (the `select` part isn't used here but the `order` part is, thus the error).  next sql query is for the actual loading of authors where the `select` part is used.  So I guess there's no ActiveRecord way to do what you want.

Comment: Seems you're correct, I got this working using two separate queries instead. I'll be improving my search backend in the future anyway so this is not a big problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just want to add, in case someone arrives here by google in the future, that I managed to do it in one query like described in this answer and then using [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) to paginate using the [array pagination feature](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object) it provides. I feel it's a better solution than doing 2 queries.